# How to get the source code for the OpenJDK project jdk8u's mercurial tag?

Tags: mercurial, java

[JDK 8 Update Releases](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/) says:

> In addition, the source code for the last release, 8u162, is available by cloning the 8u master forest : `http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u` and using the 'jdk8u162-b12' mercurial tag.

Can anyone give me a detailed command sequence for the above text? I am not familiar with Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u
cd jdk8u
hg update jdk8u162-b12
```

You should now have the source code for that tag checked out.

Comment: `http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u` is a forest. All mercurial repositories should have `jdk8u162-b12` checked out. @ngoldbaum